# webdriver.io continue script after page reload

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I'm writing an automated script with webdriver.io to fill in inputs/selects on a web page and take screenshots. What if a user action (such as changing the value of a select) causes the page to load in the middle of the automation script's execution? Is there a way to pick up where you left off in the script (let's say some inputs were already filled in at that point and they retain their value via session data but you want to continue filling in the rest of them).

As far as I can see once that page reloads the script stops executing.

If there is no way to pick up where you left off, then how do you trigger the script from the beginning by detecting a page load and then re-executing the script?

Responding to comments: I don't think I need to paste the code (although I will) because the question is really just how to detect a page load via webdriver.io when the page load occurs in the middle of script execution and is NOT initiated by the script itself.

## **UPDATE!!: I managed to solve this using waitForExist() and simply waiting for each input/select to exist before I interact with it. It's not ideal, but it works. If anyone has a better solution please let me know!**

Here's the code:

```
webdriverio = require('webdriverio');

var tester = {};

tester.iter = 0;

var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }
};

var params = {
  [[I've removed these because it's private info]]
};

var fields = {
  deliveryCompany: 'ABC Inc', 
  deliveryFirstname: 'John', 
  deliveryLastname: 'Smith',
  deliveryStreet1: '123 Main St.',
  deliveryCity: 'Boston',

};

var execQueue = [];


var wrapFunction = function(fn, context, params) {
    return function() {
        fn.apply(context, params);
    };
};

var takeScreenshot = function(){
  console.log('take screenshot', this);
   this.saveScreenshot('./checkout.png')
  .click('input.CBSubmit').then(function(value) {
     this.waitForExist('#mjPaymentReview').then(function(){
        this.saveScreenshot('./review.png').then(function(){
          this.click('input.CBSubmit').then(function(){
            this.waitForExist('#mjCartFinal').then(function(){
              this.saveScreenshot('./confirmation.png').then(function(){
                this.end();
              });
            });//end wait for exists

          });//end click.then

        });// Save the screenshot to disk
      });//end pause.then

   });//end click.then

};//end takeScreenshot



function fillFields(driver, fields){

  driver.elements('select + .chosen-container').then(function(result){
    console.log('how many selects', result.value.length);
    tester.totalSelects = result.value.length;
  });

  //loop through all selects and inputs
 for(property in fields){
    var p = property;



    //closure to preserve value of property
    (function(p){
      //if chosen input then choose from list
     driver.isExisting('div.' + p + ' .chosen-results').then(function(result){

       if(result === true){

        driver.elements('div.' + p + ' select').then(function(result){
          //loop through each select (expiration date has two selections in one container)
          for(var i=0;i<result.value.length;i++){
            var s = result.value[i].ELEMENT;

            //closure
            (function(s){

            //find the name of each select
            driver.elementIdAttribute(s,'name').then(function(result){
              //find the chosen container after select
              var container = 'select[name=' + result.value + '] + .chosen-container';

              var selectName = result.value;
              //find corresponding a.chosen-single

              //this.debug()
              //click on a.chosen-single to activate chosen drop

              var qfunction = function(link, value){
                console.log('#################in qu function ###########', value);
                driver.click(link).then(function(){
                      this.keys([value, '\uE007']).then(function(){
                       tester.iter++;
                       console.log('tester.iter', tester.iter);
                       console.log('tester.totalSelects', tester.totalSelects);
                       if(tester.iter == tester.totalSelects-1){
                          takeScreenshot.call(this, null);
                        }
                        execQueue[tester.iter]();


                      });//end keys.then


                });//end click.then
              }//end qfunction



              execQueue.push(wrapFunction(qfunction, this, [container + ' a.chosen-single', fields[selectName]]));//end push


             if(execQueue.length == tester.totalSelects - 1){
              console.log('**********equal');

                  execQueue[tester.iter]();
              }//end if equal


              console.log('queue so far', execQueue.length);


            });//end elementIdAttribute


            })(s);//end closure



          }//end for selects in container



        });//end driver.elements




        }else{

         driver.addValue('input[name=' + p + ']', fields[p]);


        }

      })//end driver.isExisting


    })(p);




  }//end for each field


};//end fillFields



webdriverio
  .remote(options)
  .init()
  .url('https://' + params.domain + '/' + params.clientId + '/?scope=' + params.scope +  '&cart=' + params.cart + '&cfg=' + params.cfg + '&progress=' + params.progress + '&language=' + params.language + '&currencyId=' + params.currencyId) // navigate to the web page
  .then(function(result) {

    fillFields(this, fields);

  });
```

Comment: Run your code line by line

Comment: @MahsumAkbas line by line... as opposed to???

Comment: As i understand, he doesn't know where exactly get error. So, such that situation i do this way

Comment: You can't really detect if a page reload happens. You should know the page well enough to know what triggers a reload and then write code that detects when the page is loaded and ready to be interacted with.